# Конвейер команд cmd с командами docker

Tags: docker, cmd

Команда `docker ps -a -q` возвращает список идентификаторов всех имеющихся контейнеров. Я хочу подать этот список на вход команде `docker rm`, удаляющей контейнеры, ID которых переданы на вход, чтобы удалить все контейнеры разом. Делаю так:

`docker ps -a -q | docker rm`

В результате получаю:

> "docker rm" requires at least 1 argument. See 'docker rm --help'.
>
> Usage:  docker rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]
>
> Remove one or more containers

И, естественно, ни один контейнер не удаляется.

Просьба объяснить, что я делаю не так.

Уточню: я знаю про способ из документации к Docker. Однако мне интересно, почему не работает именно такое перенаправление? Все источники говорят, что оно должно работать именно так, как я от него и ожидал.

Comment: `docker rm -i`? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/ -> Foreground

Comment: @Akina `unknown shorthand flag: 'i' in -i
See 'docker rm --help'.` И в документации, которую Вы любезно скинули, такого ключа тоже нет.

Comment: @Akina И да, ещё раз поясню, меня не интересуют другие способы удаления всех контейнеров, мне интересно, почему не работает мой. Читайте, пожалуйста, вопрос  до конца

Comment: Потому что, очевидно, команда `docker rm` ожидает наличие аргументов командной строки, а вовсе не текста в stdin, который вы передаёте с помощью такого перенаправления.

Comment: @andreymal Если можно, опишите подробнее отличия между ними и вынесите это в ответ.

Comment: *опишите подробнее отличия между ними* — между чем? кто это — «они»?

Comment: если вас интересует, какими вообще способами некой «абстрактной программе в вакууме» можно передать некоторую информацию (сходу приходят в голову 5-6 вариантов) — так задайте соответствующий вопрос. а данный вопрос подлежит закрытию — просто программе не передана требующаяся ей информация.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin между аргументами командной строки и текстом передаваемым программе в `stdin`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Абсолютно не согласен насчёт закрытия вопроса. Он полностью соответствует всем правилам.

Comment: @V-Mor, ну, да, полностью соответствует правилам. но вызван ошибкой/опечаткой. после выявления опечатки вопрос не может представлять какого-либо интереса никому, кроме автора вопроса (ну не создавать же вопросы и не писать же ответы на каждую теоретически возможную ошибку/опечатку). **если** вопрос не закрыть — движок через некоторое время «поднимет» его на первую страницу: «вот смотрите, вопрос не закрыт, не удалён, а ответа на него нет». а кому он, собственно, нужен? ну, кроме автора вопроса.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Это отнюдь не опечатка. Я намеренно писал всё так, как представлено в вопросе. Руководствуясь схожей логикой, многие могут сделать такую же ошибку. Если автор полезного комментария вынесет-таки его в ответ, всё будет прекрасно.

Comment: в документации к программе написано: «используйте программу вот так». вы попытались использовать по-другому, естественно, программа не заработала. ваш вопрос: «почему не заработала?». единственно возможный (разумный) ответ: «потому что вы пытаетесь использовать её не так, как задумывал разработчик». на данном сайте для подобного «мега-ответа» более чем достаточно поля комментариев. ну а подобные вопросы, вызванные (подставьте тут то слово, которое вы считаете более подходящим), здесь принято закрывать с указанием причины (цитата в следующем комментарии):

Comment: «Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям.»

Comment: а вот что-то полезное «извлечь» из вашего вопроса — теоретически можно. я упомянул от этом выше: если вас интересует, какими вообще способами некой «абстрактной программе в вакууме» можно передать некоторую информацию (сходу приходят в голову 5-6 вариантов) — так задайте соответствующий вопрос.